# Issue accessing Azure SQL Database From Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, azure, azure-sql-database, azureportal

I'm currently trying to use visual studio to connect to Azure SQL Server. After creating the DB in Azure Portal, and inputting the connection string, I get an error saying that the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException has been thrown. I'm able to access this db from azure data studio, but for some reason not through Visual Studio. Does anyone have any experience with this workflow? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For mac OS, Visual Studio doesn't support connect to the SQL database.

Azure Data Studio is only tool for Mac to connect and manage Azure SQL database.